# view documents with specific department id

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

i have a table which is department like

```
departmentid  department type
 1             computer science
 2             hr
 3               finance
```

here is the store procedure to view documents

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[statuschange]
AS
SELECT  di.DocID, 
    di.DocName, 
    di.Uploadfile, 
    dt.DocType,
    d.DepType, 
    at.ApproveType
FROM    DocumentInfo di
JOIN
    DocType dt ON dt.DocTypeID = di.DocTypeID
JOIN 
    Department d ON d.DepID = di.DepID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Approval a ON a.DocID = di.DocID
JOIN
    ApproveType at ON at.ApproveID = ISNULL(a.Approveid, 3)
```

now i want to show documents with specific department id

computer-science admin will be able to view only computer-science documents and hr admin view only hr documents

any solution?

Comment: You just have to add a where clause, depending on user informations.

Comment: yeah i know i add where clause but how.... i dont know i thnk something like this where department.depid=1??? is this right?

Comment: What is the name of the table where the department id is?